# mongodb case insensitive query

Tags: regex, mongodb, case-insensitive

Here is my query :-

```
db.collection('stubResults').find({"searchText" : {"searchText" : { $regex: new RegExp("^" + searchQuery.toLowerCase(), "i") } },"user" : {"user" : user}}, function (err, cursor)
```

It doesn't work. But the query below works with the Same RegEx fine.

```
db.collection('users').find({"userName" : { $regex: new RegExp("^" + searchQuery.toLowerCase(), "i")  }}, function (err, cursor)
```

Comment: Did you intentionally double nest all of your fields?

Comment: No. It's already been done. Now I have to work on it.

Comment: Is this wrong approach to double nest the fields? I'm asking because I surely would have to create new collections. So it is good or bad to create double nested fields?

Comment: Yes, notice how your working query does not. When you double nest the fields like that MongoDB cannot find your $regex operator on the second level of the object since it searches only the first level of the object as such it treats it as object comparison

Comment: I have no idea of your document structure so I canot really answer but if you have double nested all fields in your document then: yes, this could be bad

Comment: Are you sure the query matches your data? Do you get any errors, or just not the expected results? FYI, you are doing some unnecessary conversion with `toLowerCase()` *and* the case-insensitive (`i`) modifier. Assuming the string values are saved in mixed case, you only need the `i` modifier. If the values are saved in lower-case, you only need `toLowerCase()` the query. It is also worth noting that a case-insensitive [`$regex` search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) will not be able to efficiently use an index in MongoDB (all index entries will be scanned).

Comment: Yes Stennie I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: But query doesn't return me any records. Perhaps an issue with double nesting. But there should be some way out of this. Which I'm unable to find out.